# can you install a ROS distro on a windows pc?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am a first time user of ROS and I wanted to know if i could install the ROS platform on a windows PC?  I have never used ROS and I don't have Linux in my pc. What should I do? What do you recomend? Thanks for your input.  Herman.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414590/can-you-install-a-ros-distro-on-a-windows-pc?/) by [Hermanator](https://answers.ros.org/users/145802/hermanator/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First of all, you should start from the official documentation: [link](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Windows-Install-Binary.html).
Since I supposed, you want to install ROS2, I gave you the link to it. If you want ROS, then look in the officlal website of ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2023-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am a first time user of ROS and I wanted to know if i could install the ROS platform on a windows PC?

As I wrote in #q414656, if you're just starting out (and it seems you are just starting with ROS), I would *not* recommend trying to use Windows with ROS 1.

If this is ROS 2, you have a somewhat bigger chance of getting things working, but realistically, I would probably still recommend you get started using Ubuntu.

While it would require installing Linux on a PC/laptop, you will have a *much* smoother experience and a (very) large community to help you out if you post questions.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1